# Constructor injection working... Property injection not so much

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, cab

I am using Composite Application Block.  I have a class that uses constructor injection (using the [ServiceDependency] attribute on the constructor parameter) and it's working.  But when I try to switch to using property injection (with the [ServiceDependency] attribute on the property), the injection is not happening (the property stays null).

I made sure that the property has the same type that the old constructor parameter had, and it's public.

**Edit:**
This is C# / .NET

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, hmm... Should look like [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2007/01/09/using-dependency-injection-with-cab.aspx)

```
public class ProjectListViewPresenter : Presenter<IProjectListView>
{
    private ILookupService _lookupService;

    [ServiceDependency]
    public ILookupService LookupService
    {
        get { return _lookupService; }
        set { _lookupService = value; }
    }
}
```